# Nginx error location directive is not allowed here when using include directive

Tags: nginx

I am using nginx with Docker, although I don't think the Docker part is relevant. I started with one `docker/web/nginx.conf` config file which looked like this:

```
upstream rails_app {
  server app:3000;
} 
  
server {
  listen 80; 
  
  server_name _;
  
  root   $RAILS_ROOT/public;
  index  index.html;
  access_log $RAILS_ROOT/log/nginx.access.log;                           
  error_log $RAILS_ROOT/log/nginx.error.log;
  
  location ~ /\. {
    deny all;
  }

  location ~* ^.+\.(rb|log)$ {
    deny all;
  }
 
  # Bunch more location directives...
}
```

I need to have a second `server` directive, which is mostly the same as the one above, but with one change. To avoid duplicating code, I want to use the `include` directive to include another shared configuration file (`docker/web/shared.conf`) that will contain the shared directives.

If I move *just* the `root`, `index`, `access_log` and `error_log` directives to the included file, it works well:

**docker/web/nginx.conf**

```
upstream rails_app {
  server app:3000;
} 
  
server {
  listen 80; 
  
  server_name _;

  include "conf.d/shared.conf";
  
  location ~ /\. {
    deny all;
  }

  location ~* ^.+\.(rb|log)$ {
    deny all;
  }
 
  # Bunch more location directives...
}
```

**docker/web/shared.conf**

```
root   $RAILS_ROOT/public;
index  index.html;
access_log $RAILS_ROOT/log/nginx.access.log;
error_log $RAILS_ROOT/log/nginx.error.log;
```

However, as soon as I move the first `location` directive into the included file, the nginx server throws an error when starting:

**docker/web/nginx.conf**

```
upstream rails_app {
  server app:3000;
} 
  
server {
  listen 80; 
  
  server_name _;

  include "conf.d/shared.conf";
  
  location ~* ^.+\.(rb|log)$ {
    deny all;
  }
 
  # Bunch more location directives...
}
```

**docker/web/shared.conf**

```
root   $RAILS_ROOT/public;
index  index.html;
access_log $RAILS_ROOT/log/nginx.access.log;
error_log $RAILS_ROOT/log/nginx.error.log;
location ~ /\. {
  deny all;
}
```

The error is:

> 2020/10/26 04:11:42 [emerg] 1#1: "location" directive is not allowed
> here in /etc/nginx/conf.d/shared.conf:5 nginx: [emerg] "location"
> directive is not allowed here in /etc/nginx/conf.d/shared.conf:5

Am I not allowed to have a `location` directive in the top-level of an included config file?

Comment: I suspect that you have chosen to use the `conf.d` directory, but it is already being used by the top-level `nginx.conf` file (located at `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`), so your directives are also being pulling into the incorrect context. Use `nginx -T` (uppercase `T`) to view the entire configuration across all included files.

Comment: Thanks - I'm trying to figure out how I can do this through docker. With the startup failing, I can't log into the nginx container to run the command manually. On the other hand, putting `CMD "exec nginx -T"` in the Dockerfile doesn't direct that to the console output. Will update here when I figure it out.

Comment: By the way @RichardSmith, I am definitely using the `conf.d` directory. My Dockerfile contains the following two lines, which take the two files above, and put them in `/etc/nginx/conf.d/` inside the container: `RUN envsubst '$RAILS_ROOT' < /tmp/docker.nginx > /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf` and `RUN envsubst '$RAILS_ROOT' < /tmp/docker-shared.nginx > /etc/nginx/conf.d/shared.conf`.

Comment: @RichardSmith you were right on the mark. I ended up removing the offending `location` directive, so that the container could start, and I could log into it to run `nginx -T`. Sure enough, the actual file is much longer, and up above, it contains `include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;`. So I assume the error was really about the fact that the same location was included twice. What would be the right way around this - a) put the include file somewhere else (besides `/etc/nginx/conf.d/`), or b) don't use the `.conf` extension?